# is Django 'app' equal to 'component' in Angular?

Tags: django, angular

Just started learning Django, as an Angular developer can we say that apps in Django are similar to Angular components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's, for example we don't need create a component for a navbar or a dashboard. App it's like parts of your application, for example, you have a main app which gonna handle the general stuff and you can have a clients app to handle clients stuff, etc.

Creating apps your application gets more organized and more structured

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. It's the way of modularizing your code according to the functionality.